# Consecutive Statements in Map Annotation Error

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, annotations, mapkit

Ive followed a great online tutorial but i am getting this error.

Consecutive Stataments on a line must be separated by ;

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    var annotation = CustomAnnotation(coordinate: locationManager.location, title: textView.text, subtitle: "SubTitle"));
    myMapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    textView.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

This is the line with the error

```
        var annotation = CustomAnnotation(coordinate: locationManager.location, title: textView.text, subtitle: "SubTitle"));
```

Can anyone shed light on why?

Many thanks

Comment: You’ve added a `)` to much at the end I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a extra ) at the end of your statement,

```
 var annotation = CustomAnnotation(coordinate: locationManager.location, 
 title:textView.text, subtitle: “SubTitle"));
```

You should change it to

```
var annotation = CustomAnnotation(coordinate: locationManager.location, 
title:textView.text, subtitle: "SubTitle");
```